# Zechgeselle(n) meaning

Tags: meaning

It's a term used, with n, (to describe the three Cavaliers) in a text by Schücking.

[Edit, adding quote for context.]

> Nach und nach verloren sich denn auch die Freunde und Genossen von ihnen, über deren Kräfte dies wilde und tolle Wesen hinauszugehen begann, und endlich, als die Weihnachtszeit da war, hatten sie auch den letzten und zähesten ihrer Getreuen verscheucht, der nun mit Angst und Zittern einem Kumpane gestand, es sei ihm klar geworden, dass die drei wilden **Zechgesellen** sicherlich gar nichts anderes als drei der Hölle entlaufene Teufel sein.

-From Levin Schücking, *Die drei Freier (Deutsche Marchen)*.  As quoted by Carol Fehringer, *German Grammar in Context: Analysis and Practice*, first edition, 2002, p. 34 (intro text to chapter 6, comparatives and superlatives).

A.  what is the translation/feel for the word?  I can see that Zech is bill and gesellen is to join.  But not clear if it means buddies, drinking buddies or bill-sharers, or what.

B. Is this a normal word to use or archaic?

[For the research chiders… I looked at big fat offline Collins, a couple online dics, and did a Google search. No bites.  Also, you don't see all the ones I figure out without you … just come here with the nuanced (at least to me) ones.]

Comment: A sentence with some context would be good. Drinking buddies is most plausible.

Comment: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zechgenosse https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zechgeselle

Comment: uu:  added the quote.

Answer (score 3):

A "Zechgeselle" is a "drinking buddy". The verb "[zechen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zechen)" stands for heavily drinking alcohol.

Let me quote a bit more from Schücking's [Die drei Freier](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/schueckg/3freier/3freier.html):

> **In den Weinstuben**, wo sie einkehrten, ging es dagegen desto lauter und unbändiger her. Mit jedem Tage wurden die drei Fremden leidenschaftlicher im Spiele, mit jedem Tage ersannen sie abenteuerlichere Anschläge, eine innerliche Unruhe schien sie erfaßt zu haben, die schier nicht eher aufhörte sie zu quälen, als bis alle drei sich bis tief in die Nächte hinein in die wildeste Aufregung gerast. Nach und nach verloren sich denn auch die Freunde und Genossen von ihnen, über deren Kräfte dies wilde und tolle Wesen hinauszugehen begann. Als endlich die Weihnachtszeit da war, hatten sie auch den letzten und zähesten ihrer Getreuen verscheucht, der nun mit Angst und Zittern einem Kumpane gestand, es sei ihm klar geworden, daß die drei wilden Zechgesellen sicherlich gar nichts anderes als drei der Hölle entlaufene Teufel seien.

It should be clear what they have been doing in the wine taverns.

By the way, in contemporary German one would perhaps prefer to say "Saufkumpan" instead of "Zechgeselle".

Answer (score -2):

(Not an expert in German history)

There are 2 ways to interpret it.

Guess 1 is as you say, someone you share a bill with, [you drink and eat with](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/zechgeselle).
Modern slang for it might be **Saufkumpel**.

Guess 2 is someone who is part of a [Zeche in the sense of a guild](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zunft). Modern word is **Zunft** or **Innung**. In that meaning, a *Zechgeselle* is someone who is like a **treasurer** for the union of *Gesellen* in a *Zeche*.

Comment: "Zechgeselle" is a modern standard Germany word. It means "drinking buddy". Your second guess is some strange speculation. To clarify, a "Zeche" is a (underground) mining operation. I don't follow your logic that a "Zechgeselle" could be a treasurer.

Comment: Zeche in this context is the amount due to the bar tender. Compare Zeche prellen etc https://www.dwds.de/wb/Zeche#1